# How to correctly triple the voltage with a DC to DC circuit?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, diodes, dc-dc-converter

From wikipedia:

> A voltage multiplier is an electrical circuit that converts **AC** electrical power from a lower voltage to a higher **DC** voltage, typically using a network of capacitors and diodes.

The circuit is this:[image]

But of course, this doesn't seems to work with a **DC** input voltage.

I need to get about 34V~36V from a car battery, with at least 7A or 8A. I can't find a simple way to do this.

What is the best way to triple a DC? And to suit my needs, what are the correctly parameters of the components (resistors, diodes, others)?

Comment: Buy a DC/DC. There are plenty answering your requirements.

Comment: What on Earth are you doing pulling 288W of power from a starter battery? If the device you're powering pulls that much power for more than a minute or two, you're going to have trouble starting your car.

Comment: Presumably, the engine is running and spinning the alternator...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to buy a [commercial DC/DC converter](https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/power-supplies-board-mount/dc-dc-converters/4325599?k=dc%20dc&pv1471=8&FV=1700000a%2C1700000d%2C17000012%2C17000013%2C17000018%2C1700001e%2C17000022%2C17000023%2C1700002c%2C1700002e%2C1700003c%2C1700003d%2C17000041%2C17000047%2C1700004a%2C17000052%2C17000056%2C1700005a%2C1700005b%2C17000062%2C17000064%2C17000065%2C17000067%2C1700007a%2C17000080%2C1700008f%2C17000090%2C17000097%2C1700009c%2C170000aa%2C170000b0%2C170000b1%2C170000b2%2C170000b3%2C170000b4%2C170000b5%2C170000b6%2C170000b7%2C170000b8%2C170000b9%2C170000ba%2C170000c6%2C170000ca%2C170000cb%2C170000d0%2C170000d1%2C170000d2%2C170000d5%2C170000d9%2C170000da%2C170000dc%2C170000dd%2C170000de%2C170000df%2C170000e3%2C170000e5%2C170000ea%2C170000eb%2C170000ec%2C170000ee%2C170000f0%2C170000f1%2C170000f3%2C170000f4%2C170000f7%2C170000fe%2C17000100%2C17000102%2C17000103%2C17000107%2Cfff40042%2Cfff800df%2C17d40019%2C17d40084%2C17d4008d%2C17d400c7%2C17d400d1&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=50). Two of [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/V28A36C200BL/1102-1299-ND/2839427) in parallel will do the job. Just be sure you follow the data sheet recommendations on paralleling.

Answer (score 1):

Possible cheap approach. !!

If you have a high power car stereo power amplifier that runs normal impedence speakers like say 4 ohms       , the voltage at the current you are asking could be already available inside it. The power amplifiers are having built in DC to DC converter to step up 12V automobile voltage to bipolar high voltage e.g. +35V and -35V. The exact current limit is depend on the power rating of the amplifier.

388 watts is not uncommon among car power amplifiers, thus what you trying to get is already available.